# Confidential Transactions on Polygon Network

Tags: polygon, privacy, zero-knowledge

I can see that Polygon Network has integrated zero knowledge proof based rollup technology using Hermez Network. I can also understand that Polygon is working on [zkEVM](https://polygon.technology/solutions/polygon-zkevm) based prover and verifier system. I could see a recent implementation of Hermez bridge in the [following GitHub repository](https://github.com/maticnetwork/matic.js/blob/master/src/hermez/hermez_bridge.ts) of MaticJS. Based on these toolsets in the Polygon Network, is it possible to do confidential transactions using zkSNARKS?

Comment: Ive been looking for an answer as well. So far everything seems to be focusing on the verification and scalability side, not confidentiality. So far best approach I have come across has been using Aztec's Noir Lang and spitting out a verifying Solidity contract.